# Jenkins не видет команды shell

Tags: jenkins, vagrant

Я установил Jenkins на свою локальную машину. 
Далее Я создаю джобу с vagrant init после запуска выходит ощибка ERROR: script returned exit code 127
На машине vagrant стоит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решено] В настройках Jenkins исправить $PATH

Comment: А что не так было с изначальным PATH ?  Его забыли изначально прописать или прописали неверно?